# Nth roots of square matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is there a general method (which can be implemented by hand) to finding the $n$-th roots of $2 \times 2$ matrices? Is there a similar method for a general $m \times m$ matrix? (for $n > 1$ and $n\in\mathbb{Z}$)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix#Computation_methods

Answer (score 4):

By hand, you can do a Jordan decompositiotion, $A = S J S^{-1}$. If $J$ is diagonal, then it is easy to compute $J^{1/n}$, and so $A^{1/n} = S (J^{1/n}) S^{-1}$.

Note that the Jordan decomposition is not numerically stable, so it's generally not advised to use it.

This might still be usable for order $3$, because there are exact formulas for the eigenvalues and the eigenvectors, but for matrices of order higher than $3$, you should use computers.

For the algorithms (and the theory), I recommend Nick Higham's "[Functions of Matrices: Theory and Computation](http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~higham/fm/)".

Comment: Thanks! Could you also clarify what you mean by "numerically stable"?

Comment: In layman's terms, it means that you can easily get a complete garbage out of your data (although, it is not very likely to happen for random matrices). For an example, read [this short chapter on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Numerical_analysis).

Comment: Ok so it might give useful information for some matrices, and not for others?

Comment: Something like that, yes. It is possible to estimate how "damaged" the data *may* be. Check [condition number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number), although it's a huge area, with theory, estimates, algorithms, etc. But, generally, the [Schur decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition) is used for computing the values of matrix functions instead of the Jordan decomposition. One can also do with Newton iterations (with or without shifts and/or scaling), although these also need to be taken with some consideration. Really, Higham's book is The Book on the subject.

Answer (score 3):

For $2\times 2$ matrices, it's not so bad.

As Vedran mentions, compute the Jordan decomposition

$$M = P^{-1}JP.$$

The $n$th root is then just
$$M = P^{-1}J^{(1/n)}P.$$

There are a few cases.

1. $J$ is diagonal. Then just take the $n$th roots of the diagonal entries.
2. $J = \left[\begin{array}{cc}a & 1\\0 & a\end{array}\right]$, for $a\neq 0$. Then $J^{1/n} = \left[\begin{array}{cc} a^{1/n} & a^{(1-n)/n}/n\\ 0 & a^{1/n}\end{array}\right]$.
3. Same as case 2, but $a=0$. Then no root exists.

Notice that the roots are not necessarily real matrices, unless $M$ is symmetric positive-semidefinite.

For larger matrices, the possible configurations of the Jordan blocks become more complicated. Perhaps you can work out a general algorithm.

Comment: This seems like a good strategy. But if J isn't a diagonal matrix, then you would be confronted with the same problem of finding the nth root of J, right? you'd have to do a Jordan decomposition again, right? Wouldn't that defeat the purpose of doing it once?

Comment: @user86111 Since J is block-diagonal you can take its root in blocks; to do so you would need to know how to take the root of every sized Jordan block, i.e. of square matrices with a constant diagonal of $a$, and $1$ on the off-diagonal. I don't know if that has a nice formula or not.

Comment: Application of this answer to the identity matrix misses a root. [0 1 1 0]

Comment: @TonyRuth Yes the above procedure finds an $n$th root, not necessarily all such roots.